# My Code breaks when taken - not expecting T_ELSE, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, lamp

I have tried my code on lamp, wamp and xampp - with it only working on lamp.  However, if I swap out the php.ini file from lamp into xampp, it works - hence, I surmise I'm coding in a sloppy way on LAMP that my php.ini is irritatingly permissive of.

Currently, my LAMP php.ini breaks my xampp mysqli, and it seems to me that my lamp code must be dirty in any case, so I was wondering if you guys could see what needs cleaning here?

```
class datamanagement{


 protected $mysql_host = "localhost";
 protected $mysql_username = "root";
 protected $mysql_password = "";
 protected $mysql_database = "data";

 protected $security_table = "users";

 function __construct($security_level = 0)
 {
   $this->security($security_level);
 }

 protected function mysql_connect_func(){ 
          // ...standard mysql connect stuff
 }

 protected function security($security_level){


  session_start();

  if(isset($_GET['logout'])){

   session_unset();
  }


  if($security_level > 0)
  {


   if(!isset($_SESSION['initiated'])){

    if(!isset($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    {

     if(isset($_GET['logout']))
     {
     $string = rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?logout');
     }


     ?>

     <div class="main_container">
    <div class="form_container">

    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['logout']))
    {
     echo "<p>successfully logged out</p>";

    }else
    {

     echo "<p>Access to this section require logging in</p>";

    }
    ?>

       <form method="post" action="<?php echo $string ?>"><input
        type="hidden" name="login" value="true"></input>

       <div><label for="title">Username:</label> <input name="username"
        type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>"></input><?php if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == ''){echo "username required";}?><br>
       </div>

       <div><label for="post">Password:</label> <input name="password"
        type="password"></input><?php if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['password'] == ''){echo "password required";}?><br>
       </div>

<input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="submit"></input></form>

     </div>
    </div>

    <?


     exit();


    } // end if - no username or password were posted
    else{

     $this->mysql_connect_func();

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->security_table . " WHERE  username='" . $_POST['username'] . "'";


     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


     if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
     {


      if(sha1($_POST['password']) == $row['password'])
      {
      session_regenerate_id();
      $_SESSION['initiated'] = "true";
      $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
      $_SESSION['authority'] = $row['authority'];

      } // end if sha1 of $_POST password == $row password
      else {
       ?>

        <div class="main_container">
        <div class="form_container">


       <?php
       echo 'Incorrect password<br><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">Please try again</a>';
       ?>
       </div>
       </div>


       <?php

       exit();


      }  // if password is wrong


     } // end if no rows with username returned
     else{
?>

        <div class="main_container">
        <div class="form_container">


       <?php
       echo 'Incorrect username <br><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">Please try again</a>';
       ?>
       </div>
       </div>


       <?php

       exit();

     } // if username not found


    } // end else - no username or password were posted

   } // end if - check the session !initiated

   else {   //*THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE ERROR IN XAMPP AND WAMP*

    if($_SESSION['authority'] < $security_level)
    {

     die("security clearance insufficient");
    }


   } // end else - check the session !initiated


  } // end if $security_level <= 0

 } // end of function security()

}
```

I apologise that it's such a hefty chunk of code, I couldn't think of a logical way to break it up without compromising someone's ability to help me find the error.  If you guys have any suggestions about bringing the size of the beast down to a more readable amount, please do say!

Comment: No matter what, you definitely have to refactor your code! This deeply nested `if-else` structure is hard to maintain. Try to separate HTML and PHP more and consider using [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: Felix - reading that with great gusto.  I was starting to think that I'd reached the end of my ability to nest like that.

Comment: And smiling, you're in the presence of a newbie, I'm afraid.  I'll google why that's so, and the tip-off is very much appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest you adopt a habit of escaping, wherever applicable (XSS is a real problem nowadays!). Even your SQL-query is on the brink of dangerous, for this reason -- although escaping is only second choice there, prepare/execute being the first. You probably already have found some sites explaining $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and XSS -- consider $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] instead.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion, and swapped out to htmlentities($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), smiling.  Your help is very much appreciated. :)

Comment: Also!  I re-wrote the class on the new server (without using the old one for reference).  It now works fine.  *why* it works fine is a complete mystery to me as of yet, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if this will help you - however in **line 67** you are missing a terminal `;` after the `$string` variable.

and on a lighter note - `</input>` tags are not part of the HTML strict markup...

use `<input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="submit" />` instead